# Failed to resolve import, when trying to import from another folder

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm getting a "Failed to resolve import" error message when trying to deploy to the Salesforce Sandbox. I have a another JS file with a function, and some variables. Its called "mappingBox" in the "mappingBox.js" file I want to import some function and variables to the "mapping.js" file. What am I doing wrong when trying to import this file getting its function and variables to different a folder (mapping)?

[image]

***Here's the mapping.js import code:***

```
import GetSearchClick from './lwc/mappingBox';
```

What am I doing wrong when trying to import this variable?

Comment: You have to export specific functions and variables before you can import in another file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be:

```
import GetSearchClick from 'c/mappingBox';
```

Also, that only applies if you're using the default export in mappingBox.js:

```
export default function() {
...
}
```

If you have other variables or methods, you export them with the export statement in mappingBox.js:

```
export {
  GetSearchClick
};
```

Comment: This worked for me. Just a update; I needed to do: `import { GetSearchClick } from 'c/mappingBox';` and had to have "GetSearchClick" be a global variable in "mappingBox.js" file.